# . Prove by cases that $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}, n^5 − n^3 \geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Prove by cases that $\forall n\in \mathbb{R}, n^5 − n^3 \geq 0$. How would I need to go about proving this?
Because I can prove that its $\geq 0$ when $n\geq 0$ but when $n<0$, I hit a roadblock. Could it be that the question itself is framed wrongly?

Comment: First you have $x$ and then you have $n$. I'm assuming they should both be the same variable?

Comment: Try the case where $x$ (or is it $n$?) is equal to $\frac12$.

Comment: if n is negative, then it contradicts the whole proof that the result is >=0 right? So what cases would i need to take instead?

Comment: The inequality your trying to prove doesn't make sense because it has counter examples. For example as Arthur suggested try putting in $n = \frac{1}{2}$ into the inequality and you'll see it doesn't hold.

Comment: Maybe, as the name of the variable is $n$, your domain isn't $\mathbb{R}$ but $\mathbb{N}$. In this case, the property is true.

Comment: Maybe the question is “prove by induction that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n^5-n^3\ge0$”.

Answer (score 4):

At $x=-2$ we have that

$$(-2)^5-(-2)^3 = -32-(-8) = -24 < 0$$

so the statement as written is false, unless I'm misunderstanding your problem.